# Custom Ad-hoc reporting architecture

Tags: c#, nhibernate, architecture, reporting, metamodel

I will describe the goal I'm trying to accomplish and any architectural and technical suggestions on how to design a solution are appreciated.

I'm working on an app that needs to allow end users to create ad-hoc reports from a limited set of data. These are the global obstacles I'm trying to overcome:

**Report design and meta model**

End users should be able to go through the report wizard which consists of the following steps:

1. Choose report root (entity which is the root of all relationships eg Complaint)
2. Create filters on properties of root entity
3. Create filters on properties of other entities which are in relation to root entity (e.g Customer, User)
4. Select the columns for the report table (from the union of all columns across selected relationships)
5. Choose sort expression
6. Choose grouping expression
7. Save the report

This is a common thing with comercial apps and a good example is SugarCRM.

I'm tying to define a custom meta model that will describe the reports.
Application uses NHibernate as ORM and the idea is to use Criteria API to construct report queries, so meta model should contain all the necessary data for the query (projection, joins, filters, order and group by expressions). Is there an example of meta model I could adapt for this solution?

For the technical side there are the following issues:

**Browsing the existing data model**

How to extract fields and relationships from the data model? Using reflection comes into mind first, but since users can add custom fields to entities (which doesn't change entity classes) this is not the solution. What is left is data base itself or NHibernate mapping files. Does Nhibernate expose API for this or manual XML querying is the only choice?

**Report rendering**

Also rendering reports at is an issue. Report must be designed at runtime but as far as i know this is not possible with rdlc. What are alternatives to this approach? 
Avoid rdlc and render in plain HTML? Are there any other frameworks?

Suggestions for open source (c#, java) projects that implement these features and could be used as an inspiration, are welcome as well.

Answer (score 2):

### Report design and meta model

Datamodel would need association path, column name and column index

e.g.

```
class Report
{
    public Layout Layout { get; set; }
    public string EntityTypeFullName { get; set; }
    /// each Filter is a compare on one Property
    public ICollection<Filter> Filters { get; }
    public IList<Column> Columns { get; }
}

class Column
{
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }

    /// e.g. Contract.User.Name
    public string AssociationPath { get; set; }
}

// in code
var query = session.CreateCriteria(EntityTypeFullName);
// recursive method which adds simple properties as Restrictions and calls itself
// with query.CreateCriteria(referencePropertyName, Filters.Select(CropAssociationPath));
AddFilter(query, report.Filters)
```

### Browsing the existing data model

NHibernate exposes detailed metadata through `Configuration.ClassMappings` and `Configuration.GetClassMapping(Type)` or usefull reflection optimised access and some metadata through `ISessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(Type)` most importantly `PropertyNames`, `GetPropertyValue(obj, name, mode.Poco)`

### Report rendering

i can't help here

Comment: thank you for you answer, I was hoping NHibernate has api like that. That should be sufficient to cover the problem of browsing of data model.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create Ad-hoc reports with [PdfReport](http://pdfreport.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20create%20auto%20generated/dynamic%20columns). PdfReport is a code first reporting engine, which is built on top of the iTextSharp and EPPlus libraries.
It's compatible with both .NET 3.5+ Web and Windows applications. PdfReport supports wide range of the data sources from data tables to in memory strongly typed lists without needing the database: http://pdfreport.codeplex.com/

Comment: Tnx, this looks like a good solution for dynamic ad-hoc reports